# Use Ribbon Control in WPF Toolkit in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, ribbon-control

How to use the Ribbon control in WPf toolkit in my XAML?

How to include the namespaces for ribbon in XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [walkthrough](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-ribbon-walkthrough.aspx):

```
<r:RibbonTab Label="Banking">
    <r:RibbonGroup>
        <r:RibbonButton Command="me:AppCommands.Cut"/>
        <r:RibbonButton Command="me:AppCommands.Copy"/>
        <r:RibbonButton Command="me:AppCommands.Paste"/>
    </r:RibbonGroup>

    <r:RibbonGroup>
        <r:RibbonButton Command="me:AppCommands.AddNew"/>
        <r:RibbonButton Command="me:AppCommands.Clear" />
        <r:RibbonButton Command="me:AppCommands.Delete"/>
    </r:RibbonGroup>

    <r:RibbonGroup>
        <r:RibbonButton Command="me:AppCommands.DownloadStatements"/>
        <r:RibbonButton Command="me:AppCommands.DownloadCreditCards"/>
        <r:RibbonButton Command="me:AppCommands.Transfer"/>
    </r:RibbonGroup>
</r:RibbonTab>
```

Comment: How to include the namespaces for ribbon in XAML?

Answer (score 3):

Good link Trainee4Life, just like [this](http://teusje.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/wpf-office-ribbon-control/) one.

Answer (score 0):

I did work with Ribbon for a considerable amount of time. Nothing beats these tutorials.

http://www.uxpassion.com/2009/08/wpf-ribbon-control-roadmap-and-look-into-the-future/

And for the namespace problem, include a reference to RibbonControlsLibrary.dll in your project, and use the following line to point to the namespace.

xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"